# auto ( expression ) in direct initialization argument

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer, auto, c++23

In C++23 we have explicit type convertion `auto ( expression )`, and according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23) it is already supported by both GCC and Clang.

I have a question where such cast does not occur for some reason. Consider the program:

```
// OK, x = 0
int x(int(auto(0)));

// OK, f is function template
int f(auto(x));

// error
int y(int(auto(x)));
```

Here `x` declaration is accepted, but very similar `y` declaration does not. Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/f9zor3eTv

GCC:

```
error: 'auto' parameter not permitted in this context
```

Clang:

```
error: 'auto' not allowed in function prototype that is not a function declaration
```

Is declaration of `y` really illegal and compilers are correct in rejecting it?

Comment: I would read `y` as function template, i.e `template <typename T>int y(int(*)(T));` and using `{..}` works `int y{int(auto(x))};` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TvvffbKb9)

Comment: @Jarod42: That's not a function template. It's just a regular variable declaration. Anything of the form `type_name identifier{};` is declaring a variable `identifier` of type `type_name`. The integer `y` has the value of the function pointer `x`, converted to an `int`. Remember: `auto` only gains special powers in a function declaration, and `{}` never declares a function.

Comment: @NicolBolas: vexing parse with `(..)`, given answer goes in same direction than mine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you had a type instead of `auto`, it would read like:

```cpp
int y(int(long(x)));
// ->
int y(int(long x));
// ->
int y(int(*)(long));
```

However, you cannot put `auto` in place of `long`.

[[dcl.fct]p22](https://wg21.link/dcl.fct#22):

> An *abbreviated function template* is a function declaration that has one or more generic parameter type placeholders ([dcl.spec.auto]). [...]

[[dcl.spec.auto.general]p2](https://wg21.link/dcl.spec.auto.general#2)

> A *placeholder-type-specifier* of the form *type-constraint<sub>opt</sub>* `auto` can be used as a *decl-specifier* of the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *parameter-declaration* of a function declaration or *lambda-expression* and, if it is not the `auto` *type-specifier* introducing a *trailing-return-type* (see below), is a *generic parameter type placeholder* of the function declaration or *lambda-expression*.

... So the `auto` can only be a `decl-specifier` directly in the `decl-specifier-seq` of the type, not nested further. Basically, if you can move the `auto` all the way to the left, it will work.

So these abbreviated function templates work:

```cpp
int y(auto x);
int y(auto* x);
int y(auto const*& x);
int y(const auto*& x);
int y(auto* x[][12]);
int y(auto (*x)[3][4]);
int y(auto (*fn)(int x));
// Last one can be written as:
int y(auto(int x));
int y(auto(int(x)));
```

And these ones won't:

```cpp
int y(std::vector<auto> x);
int y(void (*fn)(auto));
int y(int x[sizeof(auto)]);
```

The exact same restrictions apply to placeholder types in initializers, like `auto x = ...;`:

```cpp
int f(int);

auto (*ptr1)(int) = f;  // Works
// int (*ptr2)(auto) = f;  // Doesn't
```